# Css and js files stalling on xampp using the Laravel framework

Tags: laravel, xampp

Xampp was working fine until this morning when internal css and js scripts stopped loading with them 'stalling' in the browser.

here is an example of my code:

```
<link rel="stylesheet" href="/css/main-styles.css }}">
```

A strange thing though, its loading fine if i use http://localhost/, but if I use the vhost I created (http://cars.web), it doesnt work.

As I say it was working, then all of a sudden stopped.

To add, when I paste http://cars.web/css/main-styles.css into the browser, it doesn't load. but that is the path.

Vhost is as follows:

```
<VirtualHost *:80>
    ServerAdmin webmaster@dummy-host2.example.com
    DocumentRoot "C:/xampp2/htdocs/cars/public"
    ServerName cars.web
    ErrorLog "logs/cars-error.log"
    CustomLog "logs/cars-access.log" common
</VirtualHost>
```

**UPDATE**
When I remove that particular css file from my code, all the other css and js load fine

Please help.

Answer (score 0):

You should use the [`asset()`](https://laravel.com/docs/5.5/helpers#method-asset) helper to avoid this kind of problems:

```
<link rel="stylesheet" href="{{ asset('css/main-styles.css') }}">
```

> The `asset` function generates a URL for an asset using the current scheme of the request

https://laravel.com/docs/5.5/helpers#method-asset

Comment: That still doesnt seem to resolve the issue. To add, when I paste http://cars.web/css/main-styles.css into the browser, it doesn't load. but that is the path.

Comment: If you have `public/css/mail-styles.css` file, then you web server is not configured correctly.

Comment: How do you mean? please read my update this might help identify. Thanks for your help

Comment: @MattJameson please show the file you're talking about. The file which you remove and then all other asset are loading correctly.

Answer (score 0):

After hours of searching for solutions I decided to reinstall xampp. The new version of xampp worked with the the same code.